# Does any country explicitly favour India or Pakistan in the Kashmir conflict?

Tags: india, pakistan, kashmir

As far as I have read, the position of most countries on the Kashmir conflict is either "peaceful resolution through the UN" or "peaceful resolution through bilateral talks".

Has any country explicitly supported either India or Pakistan on their claims to the entire Kashmir region? Or does any country have any *assertive* position that does not boil down to one of the above?

Has it happened at any point in history?

Comment: Would you consider China's own claims in Kashmir as a different assertive position?

Comment: @xyldke No, not their own claims, but their positions on claims by India or Pakistan

Comment: @xyldke China has its own claims on the Aksai Chin and related areas of Jammu and Kashmir (Pangogng Tso etc.)  but at the same time cooperates with Pakistan on the TRans-Karakorum Highway and Pakistan gave the Shaksgam Valley to China. So China is clearly much closer to Pakistan.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Supporting Pakistan

Due in part to Pakistan's support for Azerbaijan in the [Nagorno-Karabakh conflict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagorno-Karabakh_conflict), Azerbaijan supports the Pakistani position on Kashmir. This was [most recently affirmed](https://en.trend.az/azerbaijan/politics/3645175.html) in a meeting between President Ilham Aliyev and Prime Minister Shahbaz Sharif in September 2022:

> The head of state emphasized that Azerbaijan also supported Pakistan's rightful position on the issue of Jammu and Kashmir and stood in solidarity with Pakistan on this issue. Azerbaijan is a member of the Contact Group on the issue of Jammu and Kashmir within the Organization of Islamic Cooperation.

### Supporting India

On the other side of the Nagorno-Karabakh conflict, Armenia supports the Indian position, with Prime Minister Nikol Pashinyan saying the following [in an interview](https://news.am/eng/news/535780.html) in 2019:

> On Kashmir issue, we fully defend India's position, and it is our firm position. We hope that in this case we will be able to create international cooperation for solving this issue peacefully.

Back in 2003, the Prime Minister of Lesotho visited India and released a [joint statement](https://mea.gov.in/bilateral-documents.htm?dtl/7722) recognising Jammu and Kashmir to be an integral part of India.

Syria also supports the Indian position - with the Syrian envoy to India Raid Abbas telling ANI News that "we are always in favour of India on any action" after Kashmir lost its special status in 2019.